# How to free an array of pointers?

Tags: c

I've got a problem. I am trying to free an array of pointers using a loop, but it does not work. Could somebody help me with that?

This is the allocation code:

```
void create1(A*** a, int size)
{
    *a = (A**) malloc(size* sizeof(A*));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[0][i] = (A*)malloc(size * sizeof(A));
    }
}
```

Comment: A pointer to a pointer is not a two-dimensional array. Additionally, I do not see any attempt to free anything (you perform allocations at line 3 and 6).

Comment: Had you had a look at [this answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52801799/694576)?

Comment: ok, now I see answer to my last question. Thank you for helping me

Comment: @user76234 If the question is superfluous or obsolete, then please delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do the reverse of what you have done when you have allocated the memory.

Free the element pointers in a loop and finally free the pointer to the array:

```
 void del(A** a, int size)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        free(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
}
```